# Linux equivalent of WinRun4J

Tags: windows, java

Does anyone know of a linux equivalent of WinRun4J? Google isn't turning up anything. Specifically (from the WinRun4J aspect), I need the ability to pass additional/extended options to the JVM via an ini file

Comment: Since you're asking in a non-Windows forum, would it be possible to say what, precisely, WinRun4J does? I for one, am not that conversant with Windows, so "equivalent of WinRun4J" doesn't mean a lot, maybe like asking "what's the Windows equivalent of fork()?" in a Windows forum.

Comment: It's a program that provides a means of creating a native wrapper around a jar so you can run it like a regular process with some extended command line options easily

Comment: @Madden please [edit] your question and include what you said in your previous comment. Ideally, forget about the windows tool since most of us won't be familiar with it, just explain exactly what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarification, one answer is "shell scripting". Even to me, that sounds like a snarky answer, but it really isn't meant to be, I just don't know a better way to phrase it. You would end up with a script that looked something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar <jarfile> -option1 -option2 --extended-option-1
```

You could also add `$*` to the end of the `java -jar` line to pass along any option you gave the script itself to the `java` command.